# Restrict numbers and limit them to two

Tags: javascript

How to restrict my text field to numbers only and limit them in two with a single function.

Comment: What do you mean "limit them in two" ?

Comment: What do you have so far?

Comment: Text fields have a "maxsize" attribute, no JS needed.  Check google for "textfield limit numbers" for a gazillion tutorials.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/995183/how-to-allow-only-numeric-0-9-in-html-inputbox-using-jquery

Comment: Perhaps the OP wants to dynamically change the maximum number of characters allowed in a field.  I could conceive of a use for this.

Comment: Oren you got me... thanks i did not indite that one

Comment: @theJava -- There seems to be a lot of different interpreations being made of what you want. Perhaps you could edit the question to make it more clear exactly what you're trying to achieve. You may get more helpful answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function ValidateField(FieldName){

        // Get fields value
        var FieldVal = document.GetElementById(FieldName).value;

        // Check it's a number, and then check it's range is correct
        // Alternatively you could do FieldVal.length
        if(!isNaN(FieldVal) && (FieldVal < 100 && FieldVal > -100))
            alert("Valid!");
        else
            alert("Invalid");
    }
</script>    

<input type="text" name="MyField" />
<button onclick="ValidateField('MyField')">Test</button>
```

I've interpreted 'limit to 2' to mean a number ranging from -99 to 99.

Comment: Why limit it in JS while we have attribute in input tag itself.

Comment: Because of minus symbols and plus symbols.  -99 is 3 length, but OP might want that to pass as valid.

Comment: regarding the interpretation of allowing the minus sign: the question it too vague to make that kind of assumption.

Answer (score 2):

For limiting them to enter only 2 char use `maxlength` attribute of input. To check enter string is number or not user `isNaN(str)` function.

Answer (score 2):

Since no one has suggested a regular expression, I will. :-)

```
var re = /^-?\d{1,2}$/;
if (re.test(input.value)) {
  // number is one or two digits with optional leading minus
} else {
  // it's not
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In HTML5 you can just use: `<input type="number" />`

Answer (score 1):

If you are using jquery:

```
$('#myTextAreaID').keydown(function(event) {
  if (event.target.length >1 || event.keyCode < 48 || event.keyCode > 57) {
     event.preventDefault();
   }
});
```

if you want it to work with the numeric keypad, you will need to also allow keycodes 96 to 105

Comment: thinking further this may be better: event.target.length >1 || String.fromCharCode(event.keyCode).match(/\D/);