# Only allow textbox values from 1 to 11 using JavaScript

Tags: php, javascript, numbers, format

I plan for using this with 'number of month'.

I would like to have one textbox where the user can only enter a number between 1 to 11.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Limit input box to 0-100](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1384074/limit-input-box-to-0-100)

Comment: @Editors - If you're going to make an edit, at least take the time to fix *all* of the spelling errors in the title and clean up the content a bit.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Restrict numbers and limit them to two](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5578087/restrict-numbers-and-limit-them-to-two.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Honestly, a dropdown (`<select>`) is **far** better suited for picking months. It works without JavaScript, provides better accessibility, and will be less error-prone for nerds (*"dangit, why isn't this zero-based‽"*) and normal users alike (*"Why do I always forget that July is 7, not 6?"*).

Answer (score 3):

You may want to consider using a `select` element instead of a text box to limit the options.

A newer and nice (IMO) alternative is using HTML5: `<input type="number" min="1" max="11" />`

Answer (score 0):

You might want to use a Range Slider control for something like this.

Here is a jquery example

http://jqueryui.com/demos/slider/